# translation view for Yii app not found

Tags: php, yii, view, internationalization, yii2

I set up an i18n page, where I translate messages using `yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource` with the following config part:
(config/web.php)

```
$config = [
 'id' => 'basic',
 'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
 'bootstrap' => ['debug'],
 'language' => 'de-DE',
 'components' => [
     'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'app*' => [
                   'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'app' => 'app.php',
                    ],
                    'forceTranslation' => true,
                ],
            ],

]]
```

...byt the way: this works fine.
For a kind of static content -like an imprint-, I like to use an complete translated view.
So I added some sub-directories in the `views` - folder, with the view insight:

```
@app/views/myController/de-DE/myview.php
@app/views/myController/en-US/myview.php
```

So my action does the following:

```
public function actionImpressum() {
    \Yii::$app->language = 'en-US';
   return $this->render('myview');
}
```

...which results in an invalid parameter

```
yii\base\InvalidParamException: The view file does not 
exist: /path/to/my/app/views/myCtrl/myview.php
```

This error is valid, because there is no view at this path. But shouldn't the `render()` method use the path for the translation views, like:
`/path/to/my/app/views/myCtrl/en-US/myview.php` ??
Is there something I forgot?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no `sourceLanguage` set in your configuration I assume you have not changed it and the source language of your app is `en-US` (default one).

When the source language is the same as target language view is **not** translated.

See [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#view-translation) about this:

> **Note**: If the target language is the same as source language original view will be rendered regardless of presence of translated view.

So for `en-US` it looks for `/path/to/my/app/views/myCtrl/myview.php` file.

Comment: But I set: `'forceTranslation' => true,`. And, the same error occurs, if I set `language` and `sourceLanguage` to 'de-DE' . By the way: translating parts of the text with phpMessages-Feature and the same config-settings works well.

Comment: `forceTranslation` is for messages only and with `language` and `sourceLanguage` both set to `de-DE` it's the same situation source = target

Comment: @Bizley is right. You set `forceTranslation = true` for a specific dictionary, but views renderer does not depend on any one. Check out [`FileHelper::localize()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php#L93)